# SQL Server Management Studio declaring variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was doing the following in SQL Server Management Studio

```
declare @datestring varchar;

BEGIN
   set @datestring ='18/04/2015'
   select @datestring
END
```

Enough surprisingly for me, the result is 1.

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: varchar without length defaults to 1 in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to declare by giving the length to varchar

```
declare @datestring varchar(10);
```

If you will not provide any length to `varchar` then it would default to `1`.

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx):

> **When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1.** When n is not specified when using
>   the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

Answer (score 2):

When using the text type variables you should explicitly set the length of the variable:

```
declare @datestring varchar(10);
BEGIN
    set @datestring ='18/04/2015'
    select @datestring
END
```

If you do not specify the length it is identical to `varchar(1)` as described in Remarks section of [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx):

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using
>   the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.